# What is the most time-consuming part for Nested layout in Android?

Tags: android

Nested Layout Sample：

```
<FrameLayout>
 <FrameLayout>
  <FrameLayout>
   ...(almost 100 for example)
  <FrameLayout/>
 <FrameLayout/>
<FrameLayout/>
```

Flat Layout Sample：

```
<FrameLayout>
  <FrameLayout/>
  <FrameLayout/>
  ...(almost 100 for example)
<FrameLayout/>
```

- Q1：Which one will be more faster？
- Q2：What is the most time-consuming part for the slower？

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Second sample will be faster because it has less levels.

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

> the performance might improve by flattening the layout—make the layout shallow and wide, rather than narrow and deep.

Q2:

> Typically, the framework executes the layout or measure stage in a single pass and quite quickly. However, with some more complicated layout cases, the framework may have to iterate multiple times on parts of the hierarchy that require multiple passes to resolve before ultimately positioning the elements. Having to perform more than one layout-and-measure iteration is referred to as double taxation.

So basically the more levels has layout  the more complex it is and more chances to get double taxation.

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies.html)

Answer (score 0):

The second case should be better, in theory at least.

The problem with deep view hierarchies is that a `ViewGroup`'s `onLayout` and `onMeasure` typically have to iterate all of their children `View`s, possibly more than one time (if you check the code for [RelativeLayout.onMeasure](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#RelativeLayout.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29), for instance, you can see that it could happen many times). Now, if every `ViewGroup` iterates at least twice all of its children, and each of its children iterate at least twice all of its own children and so on, the total amount of iteration in the view hierarchy grows exponentially.

This is also the reason why you would prefer `FrameLayout` when possible, because its position mechanism is very easy and it doesn't need to iterate many times all of its children `View`s